# sonar-maven-plugin getting "out of range of int" error

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-maven-plugin

We're getting an odd error on one of our new github projects when we attempt to run a sonar analysis. We get the following error message and it appears to be because org.kohsuke.github.GHCommitStatus["id"] gets a "Numeric value (4275691320) out of range of int" error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project audit-config: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor
```

Interestingly enough, this is the only one of our projects having this issue. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To be clear, is this full analysis or PR analysis?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam: It's a PR analysis. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGITUB-35 with unfortunately no workaround.